# What do you call the expulsion of air through the mouth or nose; often in disbelief?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Particularly when pondering or pensively coming to terms with something, one may give out an expulsion of air through the nose or mouth as an expression of mild perplexion or disbelief.

It's similar to a scoff, but with without any of the associated attitude or emotion (and definitely without eye-rolling); the facial expression is often blank and eyes often somewhat starry (as can happen when one thinks).

Does this expression have a name?

Comment: I might do let out a puff of air while speaking French, but in English I would let out a long hmmmm to signal extended thought.

Comment: @StuartF It sure does. I am downright impressed that it has been asked before!

Comment: @StuartF actually, maybe not. I was thinking along the same physical lines (air pushed out through nose/mouth), but the linked seems to suggest strong emotion (e.g. exasperation, or even anger). TBH I'm not sure if they are the same or different, and I need to consider it for a while.. (perhaps if they're the same, then the adverb (?) before the sigh/hm/huff tells us about the quality associated with it and perhaps the cause).

Answer (score 1):

**sigh** (n.)

> A slow breath out that makes a long soft sound, especially because you
> are disappointed, tired, annoyed, or relaxed
>
> *"I’ll wait,” he said with a sigh.*
>
> **a sigh of exasperation/resignation/impatience/disappointment**
>
> *His only reaction to the news was a sigh of disappointment.*
>
> [macmillan](http://macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/sigh_2)

---

> She sat down beside him with a **sigh of perplexity**. [Juliet Wilbor
> Tompkins; *Open House*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Open_House/t-UYAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20sigh%20of%20perplexion&pg=PA87&printsec=frontcover) (1909)

> Her stepmother gave out a huge sigh. A **sigh of disbelief**! [Judy
> Prescott; *Finding Harry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Finding_Harry/m98YBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20sigh%20of%20disbelief&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

Answer (score 1):

You could call it an interjection. You might spell it onomatopoeically as *hmm*. And you would sound *hmm* with a little extra nasal puff:

> **hm(m)**
>  interjection used in many ways, one of which is to indicate that one is thinking, feeling, introspecting 
> <sub>Source: [Onomatopoeia
> List](http://onomatopoeialist.com/hmm/)</sub>

It’s not a sigh (which indicates some level exasperation).

You might find Live Science’s article on *hmm* interesting:

> Spoken with a rising intonation: “I didn’t understand — say again?”
>
> Prolonged, with ample m’s: “I’m thinking deeply about what you said.”
>
> High-pitched: “Yes, maybe — good idea!”
>
> <sub>Source: [*Why Do We Say ‘Hmm’ When
> Thinking?](https://www.livescience.com/20861-origin-hmm-thinking.html)</sub>

I would just add that *hmm* with a little puff means “I am thinking deeply about what you said, later.”

Consult your linguist if you’re looking for IPA squiggles or terms like *labial nasal*.